# Yarn behind corporate proxy ignores npmrc settings

Tags: configuration, proxy, npm, yarnpkg

Is there a possibility that Yarn does use the configuration from npm? All the necessary settings are existing in the `.npmrc` file and yarn should use them too.

One of the standard errors behind corporate proxy: Yarn is unable to verify the first certificate.

The following suggestion - given as answer in similar questions - :

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

does not work, because the SSL is not the only reason. Proxy settings (etc) must also be carried over.

I accidentally have found a npm-package named yarnrc, which gives us the possibility to change between different yarn-settings, but I couldn't find any solution, so that Yarn inherits the same configuration from npmrc.

[Current work-around](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/655) over proxy parameter. Please consider the string variable [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/980#issuecomment-257413314) in the comment.

Comment: *Please* review tag descriptions before posting - [yarn] is not related to the Yarn package manager. I've retagged this for you so the right people can find your question more easily.

Comment: Which version of Yarn are you using? I *think* this might be fixed in the latest version.

Comment: I am using the version 0.17.9, that should be the latest version, I think,..

Comment: Which `npmrc` settings are you using? Some may not be compatible yet but Yarn **does** read from it.

Comment: proxy and strict-ssl settings would be enough for me,..